# Using Indigo with Gazebo 5

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to use Gazebo 5 with Indigo?

The Indigo [install docs](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu) say it comes with Gazebo 2, which is ancient and has a lot of usability issues. Gazebo 5 has a pretty convenient repo for easily installing it on Ubuntu 14.04, which is what Indigo is based on. However, [their docs](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_wrapper_versions) note that only the upcoming Jade release will be using Gazebo 5.

I'm still new to ROS. If I try and use Indigo with Gazebo 5, am I going to run into a wall?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207402/using-indigo-with-gazebo-5/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2015-04-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not know if it is too late, but yes. It is possible to install ROS Indigo and Gazebo 5 and not run into problems. All you have to do is simply not install any of the ros-indigo packages that depend on Gazebo (as it will install Gazebo <s>5</s> 2). Then, just install the `gazebo5` package and `ros-indigo-gazebo5-pkgs`.

This works well to me. However, some packages as for example Kobuki description will have dependencies conflicts and you will have to install them from source.

---

Originally posted by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) with karma: 1305 on 2015-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-10-07**:\

> as it will install Gazebo 5

I think you meant Gazebo 2, so I corrected it.

**Comment by [Javier V. Gómez](https://answers.ros.org/users/5464/javier-v.-g%C3%B3mez/) on 2015-10-07**:
Thanks! My fingers type faster than my brain thinks.